# Convert PostGIS to MS SQL inside web app using ogr2ogr.py and Docker

Tags: python, gdal, ogr2ogr, sql-server, docker

I am trying to convert a PostGIS database to a SQL Server database inside a running Flask app.

There are three docker containers running:

- web: flask app
- postgis: PostGIS database
- mssql: MSSQL database

I use [this](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/ogr2ogr.py) script to access ogr2ogr from inside my flask app.

This is the code that runs inside my app (not working as expected):

```
from . import ogr2ogr # importing ogr2ogr.py from local script

ogr2ogr.main([
    'ogr2ogr',
    '-f', 'MSSQLSpatial', "MSSQL:server=mssql,1433;database=testdb;trusted_connection=no;UID=sa;PWD=<password>",
    "PG:host=postgis; port='5432' dbname='testdb' password='<password>' user='testuser'"
    ])
```

I expected to be able to specify the service name of the MSSQL Docker container as the host in the connection string for MSSQL. At least that works for the connection to PostGIS Contaienr.

The connection to PostGIS works, which is shown by the code below (convert my PostGIS database to a geopackage file) **which is working as expected**. So the problem must be with the connection to SQL Server.

This works:

```
ogr2ogr.main([
    'ogr2ogr',
    '-f', 'GPKG', 'output.gpkg' ,
    "PG:host=postgisport='5432' dbname='testdb' password='<password>' user='testuser'"
    ])
```

---

Docker compose:

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend
    external: true

services:
  postgis: # PostGIS database of the Flask app
    image: postgis/postgis:14-3.2
    container_name: postgis
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=testuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
    expose:
      - 5432
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: unless-stopped

  mssql: # SQL Server database where I want to copy data from PostGIS db into
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: mssql
    user: root
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=${SA_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - 1433
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: unless-stopped

  web: # Flask web app
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: gunicorn --timeout 600 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 'manage:create_app()'
    env_file:
      - ./.env.local
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Unable to find driver `MSSQLSpatial'. The following drivers are available: [list of drivers]

Comment: did you install the MSSQL driver on your container? It probably won't be there by default on a linux container

Comment: I didn't install it. However I was able to work with a mssql server using SQLAlchemy and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server before. But the driver "MSSQLSpatial" may actually not be  on the container yes. Honestly I am not sure how to install this single driver though.

Comment: Also, If I remove "-f" and "MSSQL Spatial" from the connection string I get no error just some warnings, but nothing gets written to the SQL Server db...